# removing entries from a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, hashset

So I have a hashmap which contains key as Strings and value as Integers of the count of those strings occurring in my Set

for eg I would have a hashMap as follows

```
    Key    Value
    abcd    4     (meaning there are 4 duplicate strings of abcd in my Set defined someplace)
    -----   13
    b-b-    7

and so on..
```

Now what I am trying to do is remove all the empty strings entries from my HashMap. So in the above example I would want to remove all the empty strings with value 13. So my resulting HashMap would be

```
Key    Value
abcd    4   
b-b-    7
```

This is my code that tries to do the same. generateFeedbackMap() is function which returns the HashMap in consideration StringIterator is a class which I have defined which iterates over through each character of my Strings.

```
for(String key : generateFeedbackMap().keySet()) {
    StringIterator it = new StringIterator(key);
    int counter = 0;
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String nextChar = it.next();
        if(nextChar.equals("-")){
            counter++;
        }
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> mapIterator = generateFeedbackMap().entrySet().iterator();
        if(counter >= key.length()){

            while(mapIterator.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = mapIterator.next();
                if(entry.getKey().equals(key)){
                    mapIterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I increment the counter wherever I find a "-" character. When the counter equals my key string length which means it is an empty string, I remove it using Map Iterator but this does not remove the entry from my Map. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have all these "-" characters? Why don't you just ignore them before ever putting them in your hashmap?

Comment: Actually this is one part of a hangman game that I am making. I need the empty strings in one of initial normal modes but I am currently working on a different mode for which I would want to remove all the empty strings from the HashMap

Comment: Do you have 1 entry with a bunch of ---- or do you have multiple entries with --s? You want to remove any entry that is only -?

Comment: I have multiple entries. For eg I would have 10 entries of --s or I would have 56 entries of k--o or I would have 79 entries of strings without any letters like ----- and I am trying to remove all of the 79 entries of these strings without any letters

Comment: Why not just `if ( key.matches("^-+$") )`?

Answer (score 1):

`generateFeedbackMap()` makes it sound like you’re getting a copy of the underlying map, in which case removing a key from the copy won’t affect the underlying map.  If you’re actually getting the map, then you should rename your method.

Regardless, the following would accomplish the same as your original code (but will only remove from the copy).

```
Map<String,Integer> feedbackMap = generateFeedbackMap();
for ( String key : feedbackMap.keySet() ) {
    if ( key.matches("-+") ) {
        feedbackMap.remove(key);
    }
}
```

---

If you’re stuck getting a copy of the underlying map, then you do need to create your new `helpfulMap`.  But you can still use a regular expression and other `Map` functions to speed things up:

```
Map<String,Integer> helpfulMap = new HashMap<>();
for ( Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : generateFeedbackMap().entrySet() ) {
    if ( ! entry.getKey().matches("-+") ) {
        helpfulMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I think I figured out a solution. I just copied all my current entries from oldMap to a new defined HashMap which would contain at least one letter in their keys. So essentially I got rid of all the removing and iterating over strings and just use another HashMap instead as below

```
    Map<String, Integer> HelpfulMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(String key : generateFeedbackMap().keySet())    {             
        StringIterator it = new StringIterator(key);
        while(it.hasNext()){
           String nextChar = it.next();
           if(!nextChar.equals("-")){
              HelpfulMap.put(key, generateFeedbackMap().get(key));
           }
        }
    }
```

I don't know what I was doing previously. I went for a good shower and came up with this idea and it worked. I love programming!

Thanks everyone for your inputs!

Comment: This seems somewhat inefficient: 1. multiple calls to `generateFeedbackMap()`, 2. multiple `put`s if the key has multiple non-dashes, 3. creating a new map instead of deleting from the old map.  But if it gets the job done...

Comment: Yea it looks like but if you could help me out with a better solution than I would highly appreciate it!